# Websocket local ip and public ip

Tags: javascript

I have a webview android  app that can connect to a server on local websocket  and public websocket ip by redirect with no ip provider.

To work i have in my html webview app 2 js files and 2 html file. like this:

```
var ipValue;
var connection;
ipValue = "ws://192.168.1.40:81/";
connection = new WebSocket(ipValue);

 console.log("IP value changed to:"+ipValue);
    connection.onopen = function () {
    connection.send('Websocket funcionando!' + new Date());


    //connection.send('ping');
    //await ws.send('2')
    //ws.send("Hello, Ardunio");
};
connection.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('WebSocket Error ', error);
};
connection.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('Server: ', e.data);

};

for the public 
var ipValue;
var connection;
ipValue = "ws://xxxxxx.ddns.net:81/";
connection = new WebSocket(ipValue);
//console.log(text)
    console.log("IP value changed to:"+ipValue);
    connection.onopen = function () {
    connection.send('Websocket funcionando!' + new Date());
    //connection.send('ping');
    //await ws.send('2')
    //ws.send("Hello, Ardunio");
};
connection.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('WebSocket Error ', error);
};
```

how can i auto switch from my local ip to the public ip in the same js file. Or merge the 2 js files in one.